# remove css file with javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to remove css file from document.

ths should work.. 
==>

```
    document.getElementsByTagName("link")[1].remove();
```

but, not working. 
and when I add some testing code. 
==>

```
    document.getElementsByTagName("link")[1].remove();
    console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("link")[1].remove());
```

it's working now.

what is the problem.. or what do I miss ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Remove is not a DOM node method. Maybe you confused it with the jQuery method?

Either use plain JavaScript:

```
var linkNode = document.getElementsByTagName('link')[1];
linkNode.parentNode.removeChild(linkNode);
```

Or jQuery:

```
$('link').eq(1).remove();
```

Comment: it's good. still not explaining why it was working with console.log code ?

Comment: That is impossible, console.log does not delete DOM nodes, so there must be something else that deleted it. Maybe you pressed the delete or backspace button while the element was selected?

Comment: only thing I changed was the code.. anyhow it's not an issue here.. so. thanks.

Answer (score 5):

much clear selection

use querySelector instead of getElementsByTagName

var linkNode = document.querySelector('link[href*="whatever.css"]');

Comment: very useful to remove any link added at runtime, identifying it by filename

Answer (score -1):

i would suggest jquery  .removeClass() function.
this can remove  one or more classes assigned to any specified element or tag.

see documentation here
http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/